# Changing the first day of week in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I and trying to build a calendar in ruby on rails.

In ruby-on-rails, monday is considered to be the first day of the week, but i have to set sunday as the first. I intend to change this to properly use the date's built-in methods RoR.
Assuming today is sunday, oct 24th. Look the example:

```
Date.now.beginning_of_week
```

it prints: `2010-10-18` ;but if i could set sunday as the first of the week, it should print : `2010-10-24`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Nowadays the method accepts the start day param:

```
beginning_of_week(start_day = :monday)
```

> Note: param is supported from Rails 4.2.7 only

Comment: Not so. Where've you found this?

Comment: Right in the Rails API docs... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_week

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Who uses anything < Rails 3?

Comment: And end_of_week(start_day = :sunday) works the same way.

Answer (score 23):

I've managed to make a pull request into rails and now you can pass symbol argument to `beginning_of_week` method. For example `beginning_of_week(:sunday)` will give you a Sunday assuming that weeks starts on Sunday. The same for `end_of_week` method. But you have to wait until rails 3.2 release in case you are not on the bleeding edge.

See this for more info:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3547

Comment: Now I'm trying to push settings for week start in rails config.
See this pull request https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5339

Comment: I just saw this, congratulations!

Answer (score 8):

Add this [config](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c77a949299fcddd0f6f35d9bc21888b862ff665c/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L44) to **config/application.rb**

```rb
config.beginning_of_week = :sunday
```

Answer (score 4):

You can work within the api by doing the following:

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.02 :004 > DateTime.now.beginning_of_week
 => Mon, 30 May 2011 00:00:00 -0400 
ree-1.8.7-2011.02 :005 > DateTime.now.beginning_of_week.advance(:days => -1)
 => Sun, 29 May 2011 00:00:00 -0400
```

EDIT:

Thinking about this the last couple of minutes, there is good reason for Rails approaching it this way. You have to have a default start of the week, and passing this optional parameter in, you can now store the start of the week on say, the User table in your database and allow the user to pick which day of the week to start their week, eg:

```
first_day_of_calendar_week = {:default => 0, :monday => 0, :sunday => -1 ..}
....
@user = User.find_by_some_attribute(...)
DateTime.now.beginning_of_week.advance(
  :days => first_day_of_calendar_week[@user.choice] || first_day_of_calendar_week[:default])
```

Comment: If your date is Sunday, then `DateTime.now.beginning_of_week.advance(:days => -1)` this would result in a week and a day before the current date.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is something new, but nowadays (Rais 4.2.5 - Ruby 2.2.3) you can set `Date.beginning_of_week = :sunday`. I've tried to set this on `config/application.rb` but somehow it doesn't work properly, probably it is reset on every new request. Then I put this on a `before_action` in my `ApplicationController` and works perfectly.

Comment: Well noticed. Just for reference, it is documented in the [Rails Date API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Date.html#method-c-beginning_of_week-3D)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb#L178 you'll see that monday is hardcoded as the first day. Sam's answer is pretty good.

Answer (score -4):

If you don't want to change the API you can just add '6' days to the date. I'm not sure why you want '6' but that is what you have in your question.

```
Time.now.beginning_of_week + 6.days
```

helper.rb

```
def format_date(time)
   time.now.beginning_of_week + 6.days
end
```

view

```
<%= format_date(Time.now) %>
```

Comment: this is an example of use. the problem of your solution is that i have to do this every time i want to user beginning_of_week and end_of_week